# Why is fread being blocked when reading and copying a 0 bytes file?

Tags: c, ipc, fwrite, fread

I have a program that should copy files from one folder to another. But the function that reads the files is being blocked when the file have 0 bytes.
When I do CTRL+C de program continues and copies all the remaining files which are not 0 bytes.
In main.c I have a simple fork to call read and write function according to parent and child processes.
All files are correctly copied but it always stops when file is 0 bytes.
The read function is:

```
int read_file(char *ficheiro) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(ficheiro, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit_on_error(-1, "fopen falhou");
    }

    MSG_STRUCT msg;
    int total_bytes = 0, bytes_lidos;

    while ((bytes_lidos = fread(msg.buffer, 1, TAMANHO_BUFFER, fp)) > 0) {
        msg.type = 1;
        msg.bytes_lidos = bytes_lidos;
        if (msgsnd(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(MSG_STRUCT) - sizeof(long), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Erro ao enviar mensagem");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        total_bytes += bytes_lidos;
    }

    // Enviar mensagem de finalização, fora do loop
       msg.bytes_lidos = 0;
    if (msgsnd(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(MSG_STRUCT) - sizeof(long), 0) == -1) {
        perror("Erro ao enviar mensagem de finalização");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return total_bytes;
}
```

And the write function is:

```
int write_file(char *ficheiro) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(ficheiro, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit_on_error(-1, "fopen falhou");
    }

    MSG_STRUCT msg;
    int total_bytes = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (msgrcv(msg_id, &msg, sizeof(MSG_STRUCT) - sizeof(long), 1, 0) == -1) {
            perror("Erro ao receber mensagem");
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (msg.bytes_lidos == 0) {
            printf("msg.bytes == 0\n");
            break;
        }
        fwrite(msg.buffer, 1, msg.bytes_lidos, fp);
        total_bytes += msg.bytes_lidos;
    }

fclose(fp);
return total_bytes;
```

}

In main I have:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Número de argumentos inválido\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Sintaxe: %s <origem> <destino>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    msg_id = cria_msg(MSG_KEY);

    int status;
    if (fork() != 0) {
        read_file(argv[1]);
        wait(&status);

    } else {
        write_file(argv[2]);
        exit(0);
    }
    remove_msg(MSG_KEY);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect all files to be copied from one folder to another, even if the file is empty.

The Bash file is

```
#!/bin/bash

CP_CMD=cp-msg
TESTE_DIR=teste
OUTPUT_DIR=output

if [ $# == 2 ]
then
    TESTE_DIR=$1
    OUTPUT_DIR=$2
fi

if [ ! -d $TESTE_DIR ]
then
    echo "Não existe pasta $TESTE_DIR"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $OUTPUT_DIR ]
then
    echo "Criar pasta $OUTPUT_DIR"
    mkdir $OUTPUT_DIR
fi

rm -f $OUTPUT_DIR/*

for ficheiro in $TESTE_DIR/*
do
    nome=`basename $ficheiro`
    tamanho_ficheiro=$(stat -c%s "$ficheiro")
    echo -n "Copiar $ficheiro ($tamanho_ficheiro bytes) para            $OUTPUT_DIR/$nome: "

   /usr/bin/time -f "em %E" ./$CP_CMD $ficheiro $OUTPUT_DIR/$nome

   echo -n "Verificar cópia: "
   diff $ficheiro $OUTPUT_DIR/$nome >/dev/null
   if [ $? != 0 ]
   then
       echo "ficheiros diferentes"
   else
       echo "ficheiros iguais"
   fi

   echo
```

done

Comment: "the function that reads the files is being blocked when the file have 0 bytes. When I do CTRL+C de program continues and copies all the remaining files which are not 0 bytes" i would like to see a minimal verifiable example of this behavior.

Comment: Hi erik258 I have bash file with:

Comment: It serves no purpose for the reader child to `wait()`, as it never has any children to wait for.  In particular, it cannot that way await the termination of its parent.  That's probably ok, however, as it gets an affirmative message from the parent via the message queue when the parent has finished sending the file contents.  (That is, just remove the `wait()` call -- it is superfluous.)

Comment: The first thing to do is put `fprintf(stderr, "fread got %d bytes\n", bytes_lidos);` on the line after the `while (fread)` line, so you can see whether the `fread` is blocking.

Comment: You do not set msg.tyoe for a zero length file. Maybe that's the cause. Since we don't have a complete program it's hard to tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is fread being blocked when reading and copying a 0 bytes file?

It is highly unlikely that that is happening.  More likely, it is the receiver's `msgrcv()` call that blocks.

Note well that for a zero-byte file, the very first `fread()` call in `read_file()` will return 0, and therefore the body of the `while` loop will not be executed even once.  Only in that loop body is `msg.type` ever set, so when `read_file()` sends its end-of-file message, the message type is still indeterminate.

But the receiver requests messages of type 1 (only), so it is unreasonable to expect that it will dequeue the reader's end-of-file message in this case (that message's type most likely being different from 1).

Simple solutions:

- in `read_file()`, lift the assignment `msg.type = 1;` out of the loop and before.

  OR
- in `write_file()`, in the `msgrcv()` call, specify message type 0, so as to always receive the next message regardless of type.

Or both.

Comment: it was the first, lifting the assignment out of the loop and before did the trick. Thanks a lot.